# What returns CallableStatment.executeQuery() with function call?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Suppose there is some Oracle PL/SQL procedure, that receive **IN** parameter and returns **OUT** cursor parameter. I have an jdbc code that executes this procedure:

```
DataSource dataSource;
    //datasource was set
    CallableStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    ResultSet secondaryResult = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareCall("{? = call pl_sql_func(?)}");
        statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        statement.setString(2,"param");
        // !
        secondaryResult = statement.executeQuery();
        secondaryResult.close();

        result = (ResultSet) statement.getObject(1);

        while(result.next()){
            //get some data
        }

    } catch (Exception ex){

    }

    finally{
        //closing statement, result, secondaryResult and connection
    }
```

I try execute this code, and see that secondaryResult has no data, but result has. It is normal, but could anybody explain

**1) what `statement.executeQuery()` really produces?**

**2) Can returned ResultSet contains data when statement produces procedure call? Or it is always empty?**

P.S.Possible optimization is not the goal of this question. I want the code to be explained as is.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement gets the result in an output parameter. According to Oracle tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#create_jdbc_mysql this is how to get the ResultSet as CallableStatement.executeQuery return value

```
statement = connection.prepareCall("{call pl_sql_func(?)}");
```

This example was for MySQL, but the idea is clear.

Comment: See question postscript: ".Possible optimization is not the goal of this question. I want the code to be explained as is."

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are using

   ```
   statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
   ```

   I can safely assume that your database SQL procedure is not supposed to *return* a cursor, and instead calling

   ```
   secondaryResult = statement.executeQuery();
   ```

   [will return the ResultSet object generated by the query](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--).

   If you were importing Oracle's ODBC driver (and not the generic Java one), using:

   ```
   import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
   ```

   the behavior of calling executeQuery from an OracleCallableStatement [will be the inherited one from java.sql.PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html). CallableStatement is not a class, but [an interface to be implemented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) by the JDBC developers, in this case Oracle.

   (PS.: *You should be instating a OracleCallableStatement instead.*)

   When you write

   ```
   result = (ResultSet) statement.getObject(1);
   ```

   it seems like you were pretending to [use .execute() rather than .executeQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443213/cannot-perform-fetch-on-a-plsql-statement-next), in that case it makes more sense to use

   ```
   ResultSet result = cstmt.getCursor(1);
   ```
2. The line

   ```
   statement = connection.prepareCall("{? = call pl_sql_func(?)}");
   ```

   does not *produce* a procedure, but is [actually *composed* of a stored procedure that uses parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_programs.htm#BABCDCHI). Therefore, calling the procedure should always output the ResultSet were you should be getting the data from. If you use

   ```
   secondaryResult.close();
   ```

   you will close the ResultSet with the data you were pretending to use (again, if you are using Oracle JDBC).

Comment: This is incorrect. If a stored procedure/function returns a cursor, that cursor should be mapped to a ResultSet.

Comment: @dsp_user hope this correction makes sense. Using oracle.jdbc.* library should automatically map cursors to ResultSets, see last line on my answer.

Comment: you can see [my own code](https://github.com/lapc506/proyecto-bd1-parque-la-libertad/blob/master/src/org/parquelibertad/controller/QueryController.java) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

1) While it does create a ResultSet (to comply with the JDBC specs), it cannot be queried for data (because it doesn't contain data as you already figured out). If you executed ResultSet.next() on it , you'd get a 'Cannot perform  fetch on an Pl/SQL statement' error.

2) On Oracle it's always empty (at least on the drivers I've used). On PostgreSQL, for example, it's possible to get data from this ResultSet. Actually, you'd get another cursor based result set from this first ResultSet.

```
 //PostgreSQL
          ResultSet rs=null;
          CallableStatement stmt=null;
          String sqlQuery = "{ call pl_sql_func(?)}";//no out param needed here
          stmt=conn.prepareCall(sqlQuery);      

          stmt.setString(1, "param");//just 1 input param

          ResultSet rss =null;
          rss = stmt.executeQuery(); 

          if(rss!=null&&rss.next()){
              rs = (ResultSet)rss.getObject(1);
              rss.close();
          }

          while(rs.next()){
                //get data here
          }
```

Note that in PostgreSQL, you don't even have to specify OUT parameters with RegisterOutParameter (although it's better to do so). As you can see , different databases can handle this in different ways.