# Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

**Storeproceduere**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE ADDITION
  (
    A IN NUMBER ,
    B IN NUMBER ,
    C OUT NUMBER )
AS
BEGIN
  C := A+B;
  dbms_output.put_line(c);
END ADDITION;
```

**JDBC program**

```
 cstmt = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN addition(?, ?,?); END;");
  cstmt.setInt(1, 10);
  cstmt.setInt(2, 85);
  cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
  ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next()){
  int c =rs.getInt("c");
    System.out.println(c);
  }
```

while executing above program program am getting error.

**Eroor:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:192)
    at stored_procedure.main(stored_procedure.java:32)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`executeQuery()` is designed to work with sql statements that return a cursor (most often, a `SELECT` query).
Your call does not return a cursor, and is thus inappropriate for use with this method. You should just use `execute()`, and then get the value from the output parameter:

```
cstmt = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN addition(?, ?,?); END;");
cstmt.setInt(1, 10);
cstmt.setInt(2, 85);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.execute();
int c = cstmt.getInt(3);
System.out.println(c);
```