# How do I select the row which I modified in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, sql-returning

I want to update a row after which I want to retrieve the entire row in Oracle SQL. The table and corresponding query I'm using are shown below. I want to avoid querying the DB twice. Hence, I'm doing a select after the update, but I'm running into the error shown after the query. Any idea how to fix this?

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    sid NUMBER NOT NULL,
    eid VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    first TIMESTAMP,
    updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    created TIMESTAMP,
    status VARCHAR(30),
    tid VARCHAR(18),
    wid VARCHAR(18),
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pk PRIMARY KEY (sid, eid)
    ENABLE
);

BEGIN
UPDATE mytable SET wid=?, status=? WHERE sid=?;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sid=?;
END;
```

ERROR:

```
java.sql.SQLException
ORA-06550: line 3, column 7:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Corresponding Java Snippet:

```
PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(sql);
int index = 0;
statement.setString(index++, newWid);
statement.setString(index++, newStatus);
statement.setInt(index++, sid);
statement.setInt(index++, sid);
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
if (results.next()) {
    Record rec = new Record();
    fill(rec, results);
}
return record;
```

Comment: You're still querying the DB twice in your example, just within an anonymous PL/SQL block. Where do you plan to call this from, and what will you do with the returned row?

Comment: PL/SQL requires that you SELECT STUFF INTO a variable.  That is what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `returning into` clause as in the following :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  v_sid      mytable.sid%type;
  v_eid      mytable.eid%type;
  v_first    mytable.first%type;
  v_updated  mytable.updated%type;    
  v_created  mytable.created%type;
  v_status   mytable.status%type;
  v_tid      mytable.tid%type;
  v_wid      mytable.wid%type;        
BEGIN
  UPDATE mytable 
     SET wid=v_wid, status=v_status
   WHERE sid = v_sid
   RETURNING sid, eid, first, updated,
             created, status, tid, wid 
        INTO v_sid, v_eid, v_first, v_updated,
             v_created, v_status, v_tid, v_wid;
   dbms_output.put_line(' sid :' ||v_sid);  
   dbms_output.put_line(' eid :' ||v_eid);  
   dbms_output.put_line(' first :' ||v_first);  
   dbms_output.put_line(' updated :' ||v_updated);      
   dbms_output.put_line(' created :' ||v_created);  
   dbms_output.put_line(' status :' ||v_status);  
   dbms_output.put_line(' tid :' ||v_tid);  
   dbms_output.put_line(' wid :' ||v_wid);    
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I tried using the response above and am running into the following error:

Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next

Comment: @Jared you're welcome. I think you're using `executeQuery()` method for your `statement` inside your application code, try `execute()` method instead.

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros. If I use execute, then I will not get a ResultSet. How do I retrieve all the values that I want?

Comment: @Jared https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443213/cannot-perform-fetch-on-a-plsql-statement-next might help as a JDBC code.

Comment: Can I use the %ROWTYPE here?

Comment: @Jared   Sure you can.   As an example, instead of `v_sid mytable.sid%type;`  , use `v_rt mytable%rowtype;` and then `v_rt.sid`.

Answer (score 0):

In an anonymous PL/SQL block you can do data modification using UDPATE, but to select data you need to select it into something. A variable with row type corresponding to the data you're selecting, an explicit or implicit cursor or something like that.
Example:

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE mytable SET wid=?, status=? WHERE sid=?;
   FOR R in (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sid=?) LOOP
       DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.sid ||' ' || r.wid);
       ... do something here
   END LOOP;
END:
```